# Python JSON encoder - default method

Tags: python, json

I want to make my class JSON serializeable and am trying to extend it with the `JSONEncoder` class. However, why does the `default` function take the `o` parameter when it is supposed to be a method of my class.

I want to serialize my class object, not a third object that is passed to the method?

*Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns a serializable object for o, or calls the base implementation (to raise a TypeError).*

```
def default(self, o):
   try:
       iterable = iter(o)
   except TypeError:
       pass
   else:
       return list(iterable)
   # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
   return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

Comment: You don't extend your class with JSONEncoder, you extend JSONEncoder to handle your class.

Comment: The class you want to make serializable *isn't* suppose to inherit from `JSONEncoder`... that is your fundamental misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, obj):
...         if isinstance(obj, complex):
...             return [obj.real, obj.imag]
...         # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
...         return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

maybe you're forgetting json at last return. 
take a look at [json doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)